# Is there any way to create a custom dropdown in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

This is the dropdown menu I want to create:

[image: This is the dropdown menu I want to create.]

This is how my textfield should look after the item from drop down is selected:

[image: This is how my textfield should look after the item from drop down is selected]

I have tried using https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown this to achieve the drop down but it seems only registers a single xib.
I tried registering multiple xibs and working with it but didn't work.

I am still stuck at the dropdown part and havent got to part after slection of menu but tried using https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView to achieve the post selection part but failed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var showlabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        chooseArticleDropDown.show()
    }
    let chooseArticleDropDown = DropDown()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupChooseArticleDropDown()
        customizeDropDown(chooseArticleDropDown)
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func customizeDropDown(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        
        
        /*** FOR CUSTOM CELLS ***/
        chooseArticleDropDown.cellNib = UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil)
        chooseArticleDropDown.cellNib = UINib(nibName: "MyCell2", bundle: nil)
        
        
        
        chooseArticleDropDown.customCellConfiguration = { (index: Index, item: String, cell: DropDownCell) -> Void in
            if index % 2 == 0 {
                guard let cell = cell as? MyCell else { return }
                cell.optionLabel.text = item
                // Setup your custom UI components
                cell.logoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo_\(index % 10)")
            }else{
                guard let cell = cell as? MyCell2 else { return }
                cell.optionLabel.text = item
                // Setup your custom UI components
                cell.lblr.text = item
                cell.logoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo_\(index % 10)")
            }
            
        }

        
    }
    func setupChooseArticleDropDown() {
        chooseArticleDropDown.anchorView = showlabel
        
        chooseArticleDropDown.dataSource = [
            "iPhone SE | Black | 64G",
            "Samsung S7",
            "Huawei P8 Lite Smartphone 4G",
            "Asus Zenfone Max 4G",
            "Apple Watwh | Sport Edition"
        ]
        
        // Action triggered on selection
        chooseArticleDropDown.selectionAction = { [weak self] (index, item) in
            self?.showlabel.text = item
        }
        
      
    }
    
    
}
```

This code is what I tried to acive the different dropdown item view.